# Type does not implement interface with a interface method signature

Tags: go, interface

#### Situation

- `Bar` has a method `Get()` with a signature `*Foo`
- `Foo` implements 2 interfaces `I_Venus1` and `I_Mars1`.
- `I_Venus2` has a method `Get()` with a signature `I_Venus1`
- `I_Mars2` has a method `Get()` with a signature `I_Mars1`.

```golang
type Foo struct {
}

type Bar struct {
}

func (*Bar) Get() *Foo {
    return nil
}

type I_Venus1 interface {
}

type I_Venus2 interface {
    Get() I_Venus1
}

type I_Mars1 interface {
}

type I_Mars2 interface {
    Get() I_Mars1
}

var _ I_Venus1 = &(Foo{}) // Foo meets I_Venus1 interface
var _ I_Mars1 = &(Foo{}) // Foo meets I_Mars1 interface
```

#### Problem

```golang
var _ I_Venus2 = &(Bar{}) // *Bar does not implement I_Venus2 (wrong type for method Get)
var _ I_Mars2 = &(Bar{})  // *Bar does not implement I_Mars2 (wrong type for method Get)
```

I do not understand what prevents the go compiler from deciding that Bar implements both I_Venus2 and I_Mars1 interfaces.

Note : this question is a variation on

[Go Interface Method Returning Interface Doesn't Match Method Returning Concrete Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190170/go-interface-method-returning-interface-doesnt-match-method-returning-concrete)

Comment: `Bar.Get()` returns `*Foo` whereas `I_Venus1.Get()` returns `I_Venus1` and `I_Mars2.Get()` returns `I_Mars1`. `*Foo` ≠ `I_Venus1` ≠ `I_Mars1`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, I can see identifiers do not match. What I cannot understand is why, since the compiler decides that *Foo implements both interface, the compiler does not decide that Bar implements the interfaces with the method signature. It does not seem consistent to my eyes.

Comment: "I do not understand what prevents the go compiler from deciding that Bar implements both I_Venus2 and I_Mars1 interfaces." The language specification forbids the compiler to do so.

Comment: See also https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@peter has provided the good answer by pointing to go's FAQ.

> Programmers who want covariant result types are often trying to express a type hierarchy through interfaces. In Go it's more natural to have a clean separation between interface and implementation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).